# ReactJS routing (incorrect URL captured)

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have an application that deploys many OSS frameworks, each of which has its own Admin UI. I want to build a reactjs page that allows the user to browse to each of these UIs via a leftnav menu and loads the corresponding UI into an iframe. My code is here: https://github.com/llevar/react-test, initially created with create react app.

This application is running under nginx where each URL such as /chronograf/, /consul/ is configured to fetch the appropriate UI. Indeed, when I curl http://mysite/consul/ the HTML returned is from the Consul UI. But when I use my nav, or go to http://mysite/consul/ in the browser, the URL seems to be intercepted by reactjs instead and ends up rendering the homepage.

What is causing this behaviour? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, in case you need just links to pages that nginx provides, did you consider to use `Link` element from react router?
Very bottom here - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md

Comment: I'm open to using anything that works, although was initially planning to use the nice Ant Design components. AFAIK, I'm not really utilizing react-router at this point, although I've imported it, I don't have any routes/routers declared. I don't really understand why react is capturing these URLs to begin with. In nginx they are configured as follows - https://gist.github.com/llevar/dc3d14a6bde9e169bc741c140e423b6f, and indeed I can get the right pages via curl, but in Chrome, the request seems to get bounced to the root URL like so - https://snag.gy/xG06ds.jpg

Answer (score 0):

here is what i came to with your question:
As from example for [react-router-4 medium post](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf)

I changed a bit your `App.js` and for my example it started to work, and also should work to you with your real settings.

First of all i changed main `App` component to use React Router components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/chronograf" component={() => <Home src="/chronograf" />} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Layout>
          <Sider
            breakpoint="lg"
            collapsedWidth="0"
          >
            <Menu>
              <Link to="/chronograf">chronograf</Link>
              <br />
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </Menu>
          </Sider>
        </Layout>
        <Content>
          <MainBody src={this.props.src} />
        </Content>
        <Footer>footer</Footer>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

class MainBody extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <iframe src={this.props.src} title="mainBody" />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sure repeating `Home` component is a bad idea so you can have all routes in some array and just map it here.

Home as component contains menus with links (again simple react router component).

`Link` managing all you need to change url.

You can play with components and rearrange them more properly by logic, component nesting, add react router features in but at least provided example shows how you can do it.

How i run this:
- build your page with `npm run build` or `yarn build`
- putted folder to accessible place for nginx (i used /Users/web/react-test-master)
- configured nginx to watch over builded html and one folder named `chronograf` with simple html page
- started nginx and it just worked, i lost styles somewhere but logic worked well.

Here is my nginx config i used:

```
    events {  }

    http {
     default_type  application/octet-stream; 
     charset   utf-8;
     keepalive_timeout  65;
     server_tokens       off;
     tcp_nopush          on;
     tcp_nodelay         off;

     server {
      listen       8090;
      server_name  localhost;

      location / { 
        root   /Users/web/react-test-master/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
      }
      location /chronograf {
        root   /Users/web/react-test-master/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
      }
     }
   include  v.hosts/*.conf;
  }
```

I hope that will work to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working for me though. Using your method I can route to a static html page or to an external website on another domain, but routing to http://mysite:8090/chronograf still doesn't work, the request is still intercepted by reactjs and doesn't make it to the nginx proxy. Result looks like this - https://snag.gy/H7eJQc.jpg

Comment: I see, interesting. Will check this today and update answer if any will work for me.

Comment: @llevar i checked app with real nginx server on local machine with some updates and it worked well for me, I hope it will work for you also, in case not - please add what issue did you get so I could help you.